# Sharepoint - "open in explorer" does not work

Tags: explorer

This is a SharePoint 2016 system. No matter in what library, clicking on "open with explorer" does nothing - no error, no action. This is a problem for all users (IE11 on win10, mostly, but also on win8.1, server 2012/2008).

Thing is, if we copy the browser address bar and paste it into file explorer, it works, so at least we have a workaround, but then again reauthenticating is required.

With a cleanly setup SharePoint test system, it does not work, either, but at least we get this:

[image: Screenshot]

That test system has not seen any patch yet, maybe that is why it is "failing a little less".

The usual suspects were tried:

- service "web client" is running at the clients
- server is added to trusted sites in IE
- registry settings from [New document is saving in local machine instead in library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128893/new-document-is-saving-in-local-machine-instead-in-library) (AuthForwardServerList)

Comment: We have found out that the problem can be solved by changing part of the master page to http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" (on clean installations, it is "IE=9" and on our productive machine, we had set it to IE=Edge, because with IE=9, drag and drop does not work).
Still, windows explorer is asking for credentials. Why can't it reuse those of the user that is logged on? Time for a new question.

Comment: Check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/

Answer (score 2):

I have seen issues with "Open with Explorer" when "Trusted Sites" are managed by Domain Policy, and the list of trusted sites contain illegal wild-card URLs.

Check to see that all the other "Trusted Sites" are indeed legal URLs.

Answer (score 0):

**Open with Explorer** option does not work in IE 11. I have faced this issue. The trick is, open your IE developer tool and simply change the browser mode to IE 10 and then **Open with Explorer** option will start working.

Comment: Zakir, it is solved. Further changes to the master page were required.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us know what changes you had done in master page. I think most probably you would have updated the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> element?